# Visualization of the real projective plane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, intuition, manifolds, projective-geometry, visualization

Consider a closed (compact and without boundary) and non-orientable 2-manifold $M$. By Whitney embedding theorem, one can embed $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. $M$ cannot be embeded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and just can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

We can not imagine a four-dimensional object. Can we use different figures of immersed $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and obtain imagination of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (even a bit)? Can knowing of different figures of immersed $M$ help to imagine embedded $M$ in higher dimension? For example, the real projective plane is a closed and non-orientable 2-manifold, so it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and we cannot imagine this. But different figures of immersed real projective plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are within our reach. (following figures, from left to right respectively: cross-cap, Roman's surface, Boy's surface)

[image]

Comment: Why «can't we imagine a 4d object»?!

Comment: What is the question? "Can we use different figures...?"
That must really have a positive answer, just add color to your graphics, and you have one way to represent the 4:th dimension.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Could you explain that more? I do not understand what you mean by "adding  colors".

Comment: Immersions of the projective plane, in my opinion, is one of the least-gratifying ways of visualizing this object.   It's far easier to think of the plane as the $SO_3$-homogeneous space where the point stabilizers are $O_2$.  This immediately gives you the picture of a disc with antipodal points on the boundary identified.

Comment: There are two dimensions worth of colours, so besides drawing the projection of the projective plane into 3 dimensional space, you can also colour each point by a colour that tells you two of the coordinates of that point in some 4-dimensional embedding. But then it doesn't give a nice 3-dimensional shading (the shadows won't look like shadows). To get the shading, just colour each point according to one coordinate of the 4-dimensional embedding (a coordinate that is lost by the 3-d projection), and shade by using a 3-d light source.

Comment: I'd like to suggest, if the OP agrees, to change the question to "what's the nicest visualization you know of the real projective plane?", to add the tags "big-list" and to make it CW. Then the goal of the question would be well-defined, and I might even have a few things to say (^_^)

Comment: ℝℙ¹ is the space of lines through the origin so I just imagine a line nailed into the origin spinning around. (Reminding myself when it reaches noon it's already been there at 6:00 since unlike a ray the line is bi-directional hence $a=-a$.)

Answer (score 6):

You could slice the 4D object with a 3D *3-flat* that varies in the 4th dimension.
Here are snapshots of such a slicing of the hypercube down a diagonal:

     [image: Hypercube Slices]

     <sub>(Image above from [Fleischfilm](http://www.fleischfilm.com/html/texts.htm).)</sub>

Here is a video of a (much!) more complex object, a "4D quaternion Julia set," being sliced by a moving 3-flat: [video link](http://vimeo.com/6664482). And here is a still from the animation:

[image: Julia set]

<sub>(Image above from [Creative Applications Network](http://www.creativeapplications.net/mac/4d-quaternion-julia-set-ray-tracer-mac-windows/).)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There is a polyhedral model of the Projective Plane due to Brehm, Ulrich: How to Build Minimal Polyhedral Models of the Boy Surface, The Mathematical Intelligencer Vol. 12, 51-55 (1990). See a partial  account of this [here](http://www.popmath.org.uk/sculpmath/pagesm/brehm.html), and also other articles on the Brehm model available on the web.   John Robinson transformed Brehm's  polyhedral model of the Mobius Band into a sculpture he called [Journey](http://amusine.typepad.com/journeys/journey.html).